# Removing element from array using a temp array

Tags: java, arrays, element

I know about ArrayLists, but I want to use a temp array to redefine the original array as one less, with the selected element being removed? How should I do this?

Comment: Please attach error log

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with ArrayLists? They fit your project much better than arrays do. If you stored the Card objects in an ArrayList of type Card (ArrayList), you could use the .remove() method to remove the random card from the ArrayList. The .remove() method returns an object of the element from the array it removed, so you would return that. Something like:

```
//assumes an ArrayList<Card> called deck exists
int cardNum = random.nextInt(deck.size());
return deck.remove(cardNum);
```